# Android App Keeping Random Number the Same

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I have posted with this code before but this is a different question.

When the 'guess' button is pressed, a random number is generated. The only problem with the code as it is is that it generates a new number every time regardless of whether the user guesses the right number or not. Ideally I want to give the user a 3 guess limit which would require the app to keep the random number generated the same and then reset after 3 incorrect attempts. I've come to a standstill as I've not done any java for a long time and it's perplexing me a bit in terms of incorporating it into this app.

Thanks in advance

```
package lab.mad.cct.c3375331task1;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import  android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import     android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class Task1Activity extends     AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.task1_layout);

        final TextView textResponse = (TextView)               findViewById(R.id.txtResponse);
        final TextView guessText = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.txtAnswer);
        final EditText userGuess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNumber);

        Button pressMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuess);



    // When the button is clicked, it shows the text assigned to the txtResponse TextView box
        pressMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String randText = "";
                Random randGen = new   Random();
                int ranNum = randGen.nextInt(5);
                int userNumber =       Integer.parseInt(userGuess.getText().to String());
                int attempts = 0;


                if (userNumber >19 ) {
                guessText.setText("Please guess between 0 and 20");
                } else if (userNumber == ranNum) {
                    guessText.setText("You got it!");
                } else if (userNumber < ranNum) {
                    guessText.setText("Your answer is too low. Guess     again!");
                  guessText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                } else if (userNumber > ranNum) {
                    guessText.setText("Your answer is too high.  Guess again!");
                }

                randText = Integer.toString(ranNum);
                textResponse.setText("");

                userGuess.setText("");

            }
        });

    } 



}
```

Comment: Don't choose a `new Random()` inside the loop. It resets the sequence to the same point each time around.

Answer (score 0):

remove `int userNumber = Integer.parseInt(userGuess.getText().to String());` from `onClick(View v)` because every time guessme button will be pressed, it will generate the new number.

Comment: Literally just remove that and it will keep the same number?

Comment: If I take this line out, it makes my if-else statements defunct

Answer (score 0):

declare some variables in your class

```
public static final int ATTEMPTS = 3;
public int attempt = 0;
public int currentRandomNumber = new Random().nextInt(5);
```

inside onClick();

```
if(attempt >= ATTEMPTS){
  attempt = 0;
  currentRandomNumber = new Random().nextInt(5);
} else {
  attempt++;
}

// the rest of your code..
```

also, you are using rand..nextInt(5) but by the looks of your code you should be using ..nextInt(20)

Comment: Oh lol I changed it to 5 for testing purposes. It will be 20 when I'm happy it works. Thanks for the rest of the code. I'll give it a whirl and let you know